# How to view all SSL certificates for a website using Google Chrome?

Tags: tls, certificates, google, chrome, websocket

How to view *all* SSL certificates for a website using Chrome? When I click the lock icon, it shows only one certificate. The Security tab shows the same - details of only one certificate. How can I see all the certificates on a website? Is it possible, or do browsers display only the most trusted SSL provider's SSL certificate?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "all certificates"? The complete certificate chain, alternative chains or certificates of subdomains and other domains related to that site?

Comment: By "all certificates", I mean all the certificates of a website (say I register 2 SSL certificates for one domain and install both on the same website (domain, not any of its subdomains). How can I view both certificates? I'm able to view only one - the latest I install (in my case, I had a GoGetSSL certificate installed, but after I installed a ZeroSSL one, the ZeroSSL certificate is shown and GoGetSSL's isn't).

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder: Looks like your question is easy to misunderstand. I've interpreted it as all certificates involved in loading a website - which can also be third party certificates. The latest comment looks more like all certificates which were ever issued to a specific domain, even if they are not active. Or maybe only the current active certificates, i.e. at most a single RSA certificate and a single ECC certificate. Not clear what do you want to know.

Comment: Installing multiple certificates for the same domain may be possible but I am not sure if they are used by the server at all. You can use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ or `openssl s_client` to test what certificates are sent by your server at all. Typically I would expect that the client just uses the received certificates and processes them sequentially in the reception order until a valid/trusted path has been found. Then processing stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible, [...to view all SSL certificates for a website using Google Chrome?]

Browser like Google Chrome provide no way to do this. It would be possible to visit each of the sites by entering the URL in the browser and check the certificates. This would likely result in the same certificate as the browser saw first, but in theory it might have changed in the mean time.

> or do browsers display only the most trusted SSL provider's SSL certificate?

There is no concept of more or less trusted. Either it is trusted or it is not trusted. In the latter case the connection to the site will be abandoned by the browser. The browser is simply showing the certificate from the origin, i.e. from the site as given in the URL visible in the URL bar.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, but how are the certificates ordered/arranged? Which one will Chrome see first (on what basis)?

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder: it will first see the certificate for the site given in the URL. While loading this URL it might find embedded resources like images, script, style sheets etc from other sites. It will see the relevant certificates while accessing these resources i the order these resources are loaded.